# CORS Error when Loading Images from AWS S3 Bucket in React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vite

Description:

I'm encountering a CORS error when attempting to load images from my AWS S3 bucket in a React application. However, this issue is not affecting all images, which is puzzling. Here are the details of my setup:

Problem Description:

I have a React application where I'm trying to load images from my AWS S3 bucket using the fetch API. Occasionally, I encounter the following CORS error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://supersconto-images-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/1698072059990-page_1.jpeg' from origin 'https://dashboard.supersconto24.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here's the code I'm using to fetch and load images from the S3 bucket:

```
const getFileFromUrl = async (url, name, defaultType = "image/jpeg") => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.blob();
    return new File([data], name, {
      type: data.type || defaultType,
    });
}
And I use this function to create a FileReader for further processing:

useEffect(() => {
    if (imgSrc) {
        getFileFromUrl(imgSrc, "test").then((r) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", () => setSrc(reader.result));
            reader.readAsDataURL(r);
        });
    }
}, [imgSrc]);
```

AWS S3 Bucket Policy:

My S3 bucket policy is set to allow public access to the resources:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::supersconto-images-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS Policy:

Here's my CORS policy for the S3 bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 10000
    }
]
```

Expected Outcome:

I expect to be able to load images from the S3 bucket without encountering CORS errors.

Current Outcome:

I'm getting the CORS error as described above, but this issue is not consistent across all images.

Efforts So Far:

I have reviewed my CORS policy, AWS S3 bucket policy, and the React code for fetching images. I've also tried various solutions but haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Versions:

- React: 18.2.0
- Axios: 1.2.1
- Vite: 4.0.1

Any assistance or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I've attempted several steps to resolve this CORS issue, and here's what I expected to happen:

Updated CORS Policy: I reviewed and updated the CORS policy for my AWS S3 bucket to allow all origins (*). I expected this change to allow the loading of images without CORS errors.

Checked S3 Bucket Policy: I verified that my S3 bucket policy allows public access to the resources by setting "Effect": "Allow" and "Principal": "*" for "s3:GetObject". I expected this policy to permit access to the images.

Front-End Code Review: I carefully reviewed my React code for fetching and processing images. I expected that the code, as shared in my post, should work without CORS errors.

Tested with Different Images: I tried loading various images from the S3 bucket. Some images load successfully, while others trigger CORS errors. I expected consistent behavior for all images.

What Actually Resulted:

Despite taking the above steps, I'm still encountering the CORS error as mentioned in the original post. The error message is as follows:

Access to fetch at 'https://supersconto-images-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/1698072059990-page_1.jpeg' from origin 'https://dashboard.supersconto24.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This issue remains inconsistent, affecting only some images while others load without problems. Any help or insights into resolving this behavior would be highly appreciated.